# Simply find the ip address of server

Tags: php, linux, apache, network-programming

The following code to find the actual local ip address (e.g. `192.168.1.X`) of the host server has run fine on a dev machine

```
$ip = getHostByName( getHostName() );
```

Transferring it to another server it started to output `127.0.0.1`

It seems that getHostName() returns `localhost` which in turn gets converted to `127.0.0.1` by getHostByName().

Looking at other questions here it seemed that `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` might solve the puzzle but this is also returning `127.0.0.1`

Checking and searching the output from `phpinfo()` returns no clues to the actual ip address of the machine.

Seriously, does anyone know a bullet proof (simpler the better) way of getting the ip address of the machine running the script? Why is it so hard to get such fundamental data without doing back flips?

I really don't want to be hardcoding the ip address in a config file...

Comment: Is your server running behind a proxy/loadbalancer/cache on the same machine, making `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` the actual host Apache *is* running on ?

Comment: Which IP address do you want, the IP address(es) assigned to the NIC(s) on the machine, or the public IP that was used to access the machine from the internet?

Comment: @nikc no. but you think its something to do with apache?

Comment: @zaf: it most definitely has, if Apache is your webserver. Generally, it has to do with your webserver. PHP in itself is not responding to any HTTP requests.

Comment: @DaveRandom If you check the example ip address you'll note its the LAN ip address I'm looking for.

Comment: @nikc OK, I control the apache installations, what do I need to do?

Comment: @zaf — You need to forget about anything the server is going to be passing to PHP (which will be about the interface the request came in on) and start checking the network details of the local machine explicitly. I've no idea if PHP has anything for that, you might need to shell out and call `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` and then parse the results. Keep in mind that the output of these varies across platforms (so writing a portable parser won't be fun) and that machines can have multiple interfaces on the same LAN (I think I once managed 4 interfaces to one network).

Comment: @zaf: I'm flagging this to be migrated to ServerFault.

Comment: @zaf Right, I can see that your example shows an IP address usually used for a LAN, but I suppose the question is what do you want to use this *for*? Do you want to know the IP address assigned to the NIC, or do you just want to know how to get back to yourself? If the latter, do you need to do something to connect with your own IP, or do you just need to build a URL to send to a client? In short, tell us the end result you want, and we can probably help you get there.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I could fall back onto parsing system diagnostic tools on the command line. Didn't think of the multiple interfaces scenario. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm constructing a URL that is given to clients that will use this to connect in the future. Think of it as an API endpoint URL located on the same server.

Comment: @zaf The usual approach to this is to forget about checking the hostnames/local IP addresses and just use values from `$_SERVER`. A valid HTTP/1.1 request contains all the information you need to construct the full URL that was used to access the page, and this is what you should use. Is there some reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: @DaveRandom Ah, slap me if you want, I should have said that the HTTP request and the connection to the target client are not the same. Imagine requesting a URL and the server initiates a connection to another device which needs this URL. Thinking now, I may have the solution to my problem. I can get the device to get the ip address of the calling server which then avoids the problem here.

Comment: There is **no** 1:1 relationship between a server machine and an ip address. At least not from an application's view point running on this machine.

A server could have multiple network interfaces, so it could have multiple ip addresses. And as you already noticed it alaways has the loopback interface servering the 127.0.0.0 subnet. So there is **no** "*bullet proofed*" way to get a server's ip address by definition.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid in general it's not possible - the real IP used to connect the server might be translated before it gets to the server...

Comment: I am surprised with this revelation.

Answer (score 3):

If You need all list of interfaces try `system();` to execute shell's command and get result to web-server. For example:

```
system('ifconfig', $LIP);
system('ipconfig', $WIP);
echo "Linux:".$LIP."<br>Win:".$WIP."<br>;
```

Comment: Probably will use something like this. But I'll need to add a caching mechanism on top to avoid running this on every request.

Comment: try to check `is_file('/webroot/sysconfig.txt');` if false: use `system('ifconfig > /webroot/sysconfig.txt');` if true: read sysconfig.txt via `file_get_contents($path);` This way You can easily make a _caching_ mechanism ;)

Comment: Yes, that would be one way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ip = getHostByName( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

It should resolve the IP of the host user is accessing site by.

For example, if you have your website accessed via `http://localhost/` it will give you 127.0.0.1. But for `http://www.mydomain.tld/` it should return the IP for www.mydomain.tld.

Please note that `/etc/hosts` can affect the names resolution if the domain is listed there.