# How can I get the actual IP in a linux machine from Java

Tags: java, linux, sockets, networking

I am trying to get the local IP address from a Linux machine **BUT NOT** get the loopback.
To do that I am using the following code (I am not sure if what I am doing is correct):

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");    
Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses =  ni.getInetAddresses();
while(inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {  
         InetAddress ia = inetAddresses.nextElement();  
         if(!ia.isLinkLocalAddress()) {  
              //this is not loopback  
         }    
}
```

When I run this I get 2 IPs (I was interested only in one of these) which when I do an `ifconfig` I see one (the one I want to get) is 
in the entry for `eth0` while the other is in the entry for `eth0:54`.
I don't even know what is `eth0:54`.

How can I get the IP I want?

Comment: *"I am trying to get.."* Forget what you are trying to get for the moment, & describe what you are trying to achieve.  And by that I mean:  What feature are you trying to implement for the end-user?

Comment: @AndrewThompson:I am expected to log the IP address of the machine as part of the logs

Comment: The IP-address as seen from where?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. There might be many addresses per interface, like virtual address for VMWare etc. and not everyone's interface might be named eth0, could be eth1, wlan0 etc. Are you after an "internet facing" address?

Comment: *"I am expected.."*  Again, I asked "What (is the) feature?"  Is that question so hard to understand?  For example, it might not be a feature for the user at all, but for the code ***owner*** e.g. "Ensures only licensed copies are running" or "Tracks usage patterns by country".  So, again:  What is the ***feature*** here?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen:From the other PCs

Comment: @AndrewThompson:I have a web app deployed in a linux machine.I have to log the IP of the machine the web app is running.This is the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any modern computer have multiple IP-numbers, 127.0.0.1 being one of them.  The actual configuration does not always get correctly reported up to the Java layer (in *my* experience).

You may simply want to execute `/sbin/ifconfig -a` on a scheduled basis (or at startup time) and log the complete output.

Comment: But I don't need the whole list.Only the IP other users use to access my web app from their browser

Comment: Then capture it from the HTTPRequest URL instead.

Answer (score 3):

Linux machines can have more than one IP address including loopback.  There is no concept of uniqueness for IP addresses.

What you might be looking for is the hostname (and its IP address)  You can get this by reading /etc/hostname and looking up its IP address. Note: its possible it doesn't have an IP address if the machine is not setup in a normal manner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question but using PHP instead of Java:

[Simply find the ip address of server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712864/simply-find-the-ip-address-of-server)

The best answer was that its not generally possible without serious back flips which doesn't really have to do with the language you are using and more to do with the underlying system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets {

public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
     System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
     Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
        if (netint.getName().equals("wlan0") || netint.getName().equals("en0")) {
             displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
        }       
}

static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
    out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
    out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
    for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {

        out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
    }
    out.printf("\n");
 }
}
```